# CXF WSS4j interceptor in Android SOAP client

Tags: android, soap, cxf, interceptor, wss4j

I'm using ksoap2 library to make a soap client on Android mobile phone and I need to use something like cxf's WSS4J interceptors like the following code:

```
private WSS4JInInterceptor securityInInterceptor;
private WSS4JOutInterceptor securityOutInterceptor;
Object result = null;

/* Other code */

Client cxfClient = ClientProxy.getClient(result);
/* this is interceptors */
cxfClient.getOutInterceptors().add(securityOutInterceptor);
cxfClient.getInInterceptors().add(securityInInterceptor);
```

Anyone can suggest me how to make thisone on Android (maybe using ksoap2 libs, or other libs)?
Alternatively, anyone knows a cxf version for Android?
Thank you!